# Change Background Color Popupmenu on NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I still haven't found the correct solution to change the background color for PopupMenu. But in this case i am using `AppTheme.NoActionBar` for particular reason. Here's my style

```
<style name="DarkThemeNoAppBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="backgroundcolor">#3d3b3b</item>
        <item name="cardbackground">#5e5b5b</item>
        <item name="textcolor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="textcolordrawer">#faf6f6</item>
        <item name="tintcolor">#d9d4d4</item>
        <item name="buttoncolor">#45b6ac</item>
        <item name="texttitlecolor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="backgroundcolorlayout">#181818</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#181818</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuDarkStyle</item>
    </style>


    <style name="popupMenuDarkStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#181818</item>
    </style>
```

If you see `popupMenuStyle`, this `popupMenuDarkStyle` does not give any effect in UI. Many literature in google solve this problem but it only for `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`  but in my case i need to use `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. Please someone give me some advice.

**UPDATE 2**
this below is the second attempt

```
<style name="DarkThemeNoAppBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="backgroundcolor">#3d3b3b</item>
        <item name="cardbackground">#5e5b5b</item>
        <item name="textcolor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="textcolordrawer">#faf6f6</item>
        <item name="tintcolor">#d9d4d4</item>
        <item name="buttoncolor">#45b6ac</item>
        <item name="texttitlecolor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="backgroundcolorlayout">#181818</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#181818</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ede7e7</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuDarkStyle</item>
    </style>


    <style name="popupMenuDarkStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#181818</item>
    </style>
```

My PopupMenu is attached on optionMenu (on Burger button), here how optionsMenu created in Activity.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Manual add menu
        menu.add(0, 1, 1, DesignUtil.menuIconWithText(getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black), "Bookmark"));

        menu.add(0, 2, 1, DesignUtil.menuIconWithText(getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp), "Settings"));

        return true;
    }
```

Yes, popupmenu display correctly but the background color still can not be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me

step 1.create new style

```
 <style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#2FAC7E</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#181818</item>
</style>
```

step 2.add this line in your activity where you add PopUpMenu

```
 Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
 final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
```

Comment: Actually i created menu by using onCreateOptionMenu

Comment: i updated my question, do you have an idea with my code condition

Comment: please check another answer may it help you @NandaZ

Comment: i think i accept this answer, because i changed my code to created PopUpMenu. I am no longer use `onCreateOptionsMenu`, so it will be triggered by ImageView which binding on MyAppBar, and it's works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It work for me when i created menu by using onCreateOptionMenu,try this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#181818</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Setting `android:textColor` on the theme itself affects text throughout the app. This is not a viable approach if you just want to change the color of text in PopupMenu.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style name="DarkThemeNoAppBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="backgroundcolor">#3d3b3b</item>
    <item name="cardbackground">#5e5b5b</item>
    <item name="textcolor">#ede7e7</item>
    <item name="textcolordrawer">#faf6f6</item>
    <item name="tintcolor">#d9d4d4</item>
    <item name="buttoncolor">#45b6ac</item>
    <item name="texttitlecolor">#ede7e7</item>
    <item name="backgroundcolorlayout">#181818</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#181818</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ede7e7</item>
<!--The "android:" prefix is for a regular widget, such as android.widget.PopupMenu,
while the ones without this prefix are for the support library versions of these widgets-->
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuDarkStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuDarkStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="popupMenuDarkStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#181818</item>
</style>
```

Using `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` as the parent might not be necessary, but I included it because that's how mine is set up and it works. The key is probably `android:popupMenuStyle` rather than `popupMenuStyle`.

Comment: Sorry, still not worked for me. I updated question what i wrote based on your idea